# Why do I have to call "delete" twice when I have each two pointers at same memory?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I allocated the heap memory to a pointer variable `'k'` by using `new`, and copied it in another pointer variable `'d'`.

In that case, I thought these two variables point to the same memory, so the `"delete"` that memory was needed in just one variable; whatever `'k'` or `'d'`. When I did `delete k`, however, the `'k'` and `'d'` point the memory yet.

So I did `delete d`, and `Abort trap 6 error` appeared.

Here is my test code.

```
int* k;
k = new int(5);

int* d = k;

cout<<"d's : "<<d<<endl;
cout<<"k's : "<<k<<endl;

delete d;

cout<<"d's : "<<d<<endl;
cout<<"k's : "<<k<<endl;

delete k;

cout<<"d's : "<<d<<endl;
cout<<"k's : "<<k<<endl;
```

The result is

> d's : 0x7fbb56c02ae0
>   k's : 0x7fbb56c02ae0
>   d's : 0x7fbb56c02ae0
>   k's : 0x7fbb56c02ae0
>
> Abort trap: 6

I expected that the accessing `'k'` and `'d'` made the `segment error` after when I did `delete d`, because I deleted the Memory!

What am I missing, can someone help me with this ?

Comment: Calling `delete` two times is _undefined behavior_. I am not clear about what you're asking here? Also dereferencing a pointer that was deleted is _undefined behavior_. You cannot expect something like a _"segment error"_.

Comment: Deleting a pointer does not nullify it. It would be wasting of resources.

Comment: See here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-problem-of-deleting-an-already-deleted-pointer-in-C++

Comment: The key thing to remember when learning C++ is that just because your code is wrong, doesn't mean the program will fail in the way you expect. Undefined Behavior is nasty because it could appear like everything is working.

Comment: You don't "have to" call twice, you "must not" !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I did `delete k`, however, the `k` and `d` point the memory yet.

Invoking `operator delete` on some pointer will ask the operating system to release the memory associated with this pointer, but doesn't change the value of the pointer itself. `k` and `d` simply continue pointing to that same location in memory, which is released in the mean time.

That's why sometimes people set a pointer to `nullptr` after `delete`-ing it. In your case, this would have saved you from undefined behavior:

```
delete d;

d = nullptr;
k = nullptr; // Both must be re-assigned

delete k; // Ok, delete on a nullptr is a no-op
```

Comment: The value of the pointer variable will not be changed although the memory was released  << I realized that this fact made me so confused. Thank you so much! I hope you have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

When you `delete` something, you are not *destroying* memory, you are just marking it as unused. (You may also run cleanup code contained in destructors, but that's another story.) The memory itself, i.e. the physical bits and bytes, remain in place just as before.

As such, when you `delete` a pointer, the pointer still remains pointing to the same bytes in physical memory after the fact **but you are not allowed to use them anymore**. If you do, anything is allowed to happen. This even applies to the pointer itself: Any pointer that points to `delete`d memory must not be touched anymore, it's immediately invalid.

If you do use a pointer after it's been `delete`d, it *may* appear to work correctly. Or you *may* crash. Or you *may* access some other memory object that has been created using the same physical bytes of memory. **You simply don't know what will actually happen**.

As such, your initial idea is correct: Only exactly one of the two pointers needs the `delete`, the other of the two must not be touched after the fact:

```
int* k;
k = new int(5);

int* d = k;

cout<<"d's : "<<d<<endl;
cout<<"k's : "<<k<<endl;

delete d;

// cout<<"d's : "<<d<<endl;    //Undefined behavior, the pointer is invalid now
// cout<<"k's : "<<k<<endl;    //Undefined behavior, k is invalid as well

// delete k;    //Undefined behavior, k is invalid
```

Comment: Don't understand why printing values of pointers `k` and `d` after `delete` is UB. You don't dereference these pointers any way.

Comment: @DanielLangr For a very long time, I didn't know as well, having grown up on architectures where pointers are held in normal general purpose registers. However, there are some architectures that use specialized pointer registers that include a segment part, and loading an invalid value into that segment pointer part raises a hardware exception. These architectures are the reason why it's illegal in C/C++ to even pass around an invalid pointer. On modern architectures, this is a non-issue, but the language rule remains.

Comment: Fair point. How about the C++ Standard? Does it specify that reading a value of an invalid pointer is UB? Just curious.

Comment: I think I have found it: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc#4.sentence-3. The behavior seems to be implementation-defined since C++14 (and undefined in C++11). Thanks for pointing this out, learned something new today :).

Comment: @DanielLangr Always glad to help :-) That's what I appreciate SO discussions for: I learn so much from them :-)